# APPIUM: Cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:8200

Tags: python, android, appium

Suddenly I’m Facing this error when I try to run appium.

**Error:**
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: ‘Command ‘C:\Users\vsingh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:8200 tcp:6790’ exited with code 1’; Stderr: ‘adb.exe: error: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:8200: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)’; Code: ‘1’

**desired Cap:**

```
{
“deviceName”: “myphone”,
“udid”: “emulator-5554”,
“platformName”: “Android”,
“platformVersion”: “9.0”,
“appWaitActivity”: “com.application.activity.MainDrawerActivity”,
“appWaitPackage”: “com.application.pas”,
“noReset”: true
}
```

Tried adb kill-server, adb root. but still no effect.
It was working fine till yesterday.

Using Appium Inspector

Answer (score 0):

Most likely port is left in-use.

Try running `sudo lsof -i | grep 8080` or `nc -l 0.0.0.0 8080` on machine terminal, whatever works to see if port in use.

If it is in use, then stop the process. The best way to avoid it in future is either create cleanup scripts to free all required ports before you start tests again or run tests in docker container.